# How to use windows shell enter a directory with location "\\psf\Home\Documents\"?

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-shell

I use parallels desktop run a Windows 7 virtual machine. In that Windows, shared files(between virtual machine and real machine) are in a network location, for example, like `\\psf\Home\Documents\Visual Studio 2012`.

[image: location]

`文档库` are Chinese characters and they means documents.

[image: location]

`网络` are Chinese characters and they means network.

I tried so many ways to enter that location but all failed.

[image: cmd]

So, could any one please tell me how to do that?

Comment: have you tried making a mapped drive to that unc path? That may be easier from the shell.

Comment: @DarrenKopp It works! You save me from that hell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pushd` command. It handles creating mapped drive for you. `popd` will return you back and remove mapped drive.

```
pushd \\psf\Home
```

Comment: A windows-shell solution to that problem. thanks.